# Issue with shirt -> colors -> sizes laravel relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to wrap my head about this relationship which I think is many-to-many, I have 3 models, a shirt model, a shirt color model and a shirtsize model. Now this is how I see things, I could say:

One shirt can be many colors and many sizes but you could also say a shirt will be ONE color and ONE size (a shirt can't be multiple colors/sizes at once...) , so this got me pretty confused. I got the feeling this has to be a many to many relationship between shirt, size and color but I'm not so sure how (and if I should) do  this?

This are my migrations:

```
Schema::create('shirts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('slug')->unique();
            $table->string('url')->unique();
            $table->string('title')->unique();
            $table->longText('body');
            $table->decimal('finalPrice', 5,2);
            $table->integer('totalCount');
            $table->string('image')->nullable();
            $table->boolean('isVisible')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('beenPublished')->default(false);
            $table->boolean('scheduleForMail')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });


Schema::create('shirtcolors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('title');
            $table->string('hexColor');
            $table->timestamps();
        });



Schema::create('shirtsizes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id'); 
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Are there going to be instances where a size/colour combination is not available? I.E. SM/Blue, SM/Red and MD/Blue are available, but MD/Red is not? (Or something similar)

Comment: Yes I think so, each shirt will also have a stock left attribute.

Comment: Alrighty. Then (personally), I would have a single table for `shirts` (think product), and a single table for `shirt_variations`. On that table, I'd have `colour` (or `colour_id` if you want to store colours in a separate table), and same for `size` (or `size_id`). You could attach different prices/stock to a column on that table too, and just include a row for each variation. Someone may have a better solution, but those are my thoughts. This question may fall under the "Primarily opinion-based" close reason though.

Answer (score 0):

Create table "shirt_size_colors"

```
php artisan make:migration create_shirt_size_colors_table
```

In migration:

```
Schema::create('shirt_size_colors', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('shirt_id');
            $table->foreign('shirt_id')->references('id')->on('shirts')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('color_id');
            $table->foreign('color_id')->references('id')->on('shirtcolors')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('size_id');
            $table->foreign('size_id')->references('id')->on('shirtsizes')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**As per your question, you can add here one shirt with a single color and single size
and one shirt with multiple colors and sizes.**

For Example:

For One shirt with one color and one size
shirt ID 1,  color ID 1, size ID 1
then table entry as per below

```
-------------------------------------
shirt_id   |  color_id  |  size_id   |
-------------------------------------
    1      |      1     |      1     |
-------------------------------------
```

For One shirt with multiple colors and multiple sizes
shirt ID 2,  color ID [1,2], size ID [1,2]
then table entry as per below

```
-------------------------------------
shirt_id   |  color_id  |  size_id   |
-------------------------------------
    2      |      1     |      1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
    2      |      1     |      2     |
-------------------------------------
------------------------------------
    2      |      2     |      1     |
-------------------------------------
-------------------------------------
    2      |      2     |      2     |
-------------------------------------
```

Create model

```
php artisan make:model ShirtSizeColors
```

In ShirtSizeColors model

Here I use  Shirt, ShirtSize, ShirtColor model you can replace with your model name

```
protected $table = 'shirt_size_colors';

    public $timestamps = true;

    protected $fillable = ['shirt_id', 'color_id', 'size_id'];

    //for shirt data
    public function shirt(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Shirt::class, 'shirt_id');
    }

    //for color data
    public function color(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ShirtColor::class, 'color_id');
    }

    //for size data
    public function size(){
        return $this->belongsTo(ShirtSize::class, 'size_id');
    }
```

Now relationship in shirt model

```
// for get shirt colors and sizes
    public function shirt_size_colors(){
        return $this->hasMany(ShirtSizeColors::class, 'shirt_id');
    }
```